# Is Variance/Mean Ratio a good indicator for stability?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I am dealing with some time series data and I would like to compare 4 companies. I censored them due to confidentiality.

My assumption is like this:
VMR, index of dispersion, can be used to find most stable/stationary data

Is this a correct approach, if not, do you have any suggestions for a more correct approach?

[Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfnZU.png)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.